# Vim: run code in the same external program each time

Tags: matlab, vim

I know I can run my code in vim using an external program, but I want that program to stay up and receive my code each time - as opposed to re-running the external program every time.

For example: I edit my Matlab file in vim, and I want to run it. But, I want the matlab instance to be in the background and that vim will use the same instance to keep running my files when I want, instead of opening an new matlab each time.

Is that possible?
Thanks.

Comment: add an "&" at the end of your matlab instance invocation.

Comment: I don't see how, this just opens matlab normally and doesn't run my code...

Comment: How about setting Vim as Matlab's editor, and running Vim from Matlab rather than the other way round? http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/change-default-editor.html

Comment: The problem is this just opens my file in vim, but I want some integration: at least, running the file etc.

Answer (score 5):

When you can configure the external program (or maybe add a wrapper around it) to automatically re-run the file whenever it is modified (in Vim by saving it, or from anywhere else), there's nothing to actually trigger from Vim (except maybe the initial program launch). This is the ideal situation.

In all other cases, you need a notification mechanism from Vim to the external program. Whether this is possible and how it is performed depends on the external program, but usually this is difficult. There are some plugins that e.g. reload an HTML page in the browser whenever it is saved, but I'm afraid there cannot be a generic solution. It's best to re-think your entire approach, then.

Comment: I guess it would be 'easier' to find a key binding xml for Matlab which implements vim commands... but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't like vi-key modes in other applications very much. Once you're hooked on Vim, you want it all, not just a 95%-emulation with exceptions and caveats. The only place this works for me is in Firefox with Vimperator / Pentadactyl, but that's because I only navigate, not actually edit there.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly had this problem for matlab as well. 
What I did is a mapping that:
- copies the edited file name (or part of it) to a temporary clipboard
- uses wmcrtl to switch to matlab
Then I'm into matlab, so I just type "Ctrl-V" and the scripts runs.
It is possible to then automatically go back to vim.
See examples here:
[Vim and matlab GUI - Emulate matlab Run (<F5>) with Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250367/vim-and-matlab-gui-emulate-matlab-run-f5-with-vim)

Comment: Just in case, you are looking for this functionality as well:
I like the matlab gui for the errors and warning. But, sometimes, when you click on them, it does not open vim. You have to ovveride the opentoline.m function to open a vim server at the correct file and line. I hope it helps.