# Cell mode in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

Say I have a buffer with code (in this case Python) organized as follows:

```
.. cell 1 ..
## 
.. cell 2 ..

# this is a comment

### this is also a comment

.. still cell 2 ..

  ##
  .. cell 3 (code that is indented)
```

The sequence of characters `##` is meant to delimit `cells` (code regions/blocks) in the buffer. The caracter `#` starts a comment in Python, so `##` is treated as a comment by the language. Similar constructions could be built in e.g. Elisp  with `;;` or other programming languages.

I would like to define an **Emacs command** that when invoked, it defines the current `cell` (i.e. the `cell` on which [point](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Point.html)/cursor currently sits.) to be the Emacs **[`region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html#Mark)** (i.e. it highlights the cell).

How can I do this in Emacs?

For reference:

- The is akin to the notion of cells or [code sections](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html) in MATLAB
- Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093306/how-to-implement-matlab-like-cell-mode-in-vim) for implementing this functionality in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
(defun python-inside-comment-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line 1)
    (looking-at "^#")))

(defun python-select-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char
   (if (re-search-backward "^\\s-*##[^#]" nil t)
       (match-end 0)
     (point-min)))
  (while (and (python-inside-comment-p)
              (eq 0 (forward-line 1)))
    nil)
  (set-mark (point))
  (goto-char
   (if (re-search-forward "^\\s-*\\(##[^#]\\)" nil t)
       (- (match-beginning 1) 2)
     (point-max))))
```

Tested with:

```
print "Beautiful is better than ugly."
##
print "Explicit is better than implicit."
print "Simple is better than complex."
print "Complex is better than complicated."
# this is a comment
print "Flat is better than nested."
### this is also a comment
print "Sparse is better than dense."
##
print "Readability counts."
print "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."
print "Although practicality beats purity."
print "Errors should never pass silently."
print "Unless explicitly silenced."
```

Works OK.
Is there a reason not to use indentation levels rather than comments as anchors?

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind elaborating on the difference between this approach and that of @legoscia?

Comment: Mine skips comments. Otherwise they're same.

Comment: Thanks - I am having problems making it work when `##` is indented. Any thoughts on how to fix it? (I updated the last cell in the OP to show this)

Answer (score 2):

That would be something like this:

```lisp
(defun mark-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (search-backward-regexp "^##\\($\\|[^#]\\)" nil 'noerror)
  (push-mark)
  (end-of-line)
  (search-forward-regexp "^##\\($\\|[^#]\\)" nil 'noerror)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (activate-mark))
```

For me, it doesn't highlight the cell (you can do that manually with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>), even though that is what `activate-mark` should do, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc38), there are two packages:

[python-x](https://github.com/wavexx/python-x.el) also provides some additional features

[python-cell](https://github.com/thisch/python-cell.el) provides Matlab-like cells in python buffers